# How can I get the text of a label using Jquery in this particular case ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example in the code below , I would like get the text Salutation of a the label tag with class description in the code below , tried to select the class but it's not working .. how can I select the  text of the label uniquely according to the id of the label ?

```
<tr id="salutation_id" class="edit_tr" border="0">
    <td class="edit_td">
    <div id="salutation_id" class="unique_ids database_key">
    <span id="first_salutation_id">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">
    <label id="label_salutation_id" class="description">Salutation</label>
    </h1>
    </span>
    <input id="first_input_salutation_id" class="editbox" type="text" value="Salutation" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol class="ui-droppable ui-sortable" style="">
    <li class="placeholder">Add "Salutation" here</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get it with [ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), this is the way: `$('#label_salutation_id').text()`.

You mention "with [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) description", then you can use this: `$('label.description').text();` if you just have one `<label>` element with that class.

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FhyB4/)**

Answer (score 1):

[Even better](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
var label = document.getElementById('label_salutation_id'),
    text = label.textContent || label.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to select more than this one salutation, you can use:

```
jQuery('label.description')
```

to select all `label` elements with the class `description`.